# IntelliSense is giving a weird message: "lnt-arithmetic-overflow"

Tags: c++, intellisense

I have this simple function

```
void func(std::string s, std::string target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - target.length(); i++)
    {
        s.substr(i, i + target.length());
    }
}
```

IntelliSense highlights the `i` in `i + target.length()` and gives the following message.

```
lnt-arithmetic-overflow: A sub-expression may overflow before being assigned to a wider type.
```

It suggests that I fix this potential error by changing `i` to

```
static_cast<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::size_type>(i)
```

**First Question:** What does this message mean in this context? I read the Microsoft description, but it was too complex for me to understand.

**Second Question:** Is there a simpler way to get rid of this message, like a different way to write the operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int + int` might overflow is what it's telling you. And, since it will be converted to a larger type anyway, you should convert before the addition. For example, say `i` is `2'000'000'000` and `target.length()` is `1'000'000'000`. This results in `3'000'000'000` which would overflow a 32-bit int. However, if one of the values was `size_t` (64-bit, assuming you're on x64 or similar), then there's no overflow.

In general, if you're doing a `for` loop over a standard container (string, map, vector, etc.), then you should use `size_t` for your loop counter instead of `int`. `size_t` is unsigned, and is the parameter types which `substr` uses anyway.

To get rid of the warning:

```
void func(std::string s, std::string target) {
    if ( s.length() > target.length() ) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length() - target.length(); i++) {
            s.substr(i, i + target.length());
        }
    }
}
```

This type of warning is often not a problem (for example, you probably don't have strings that are in the lengths of billions); however, the static analyzer doesn't know that, and generally it's good to pay attention to those warnigs, and make changes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

It is worried about overflow happening before it gets to the function.  The input to the function is likely a pointer-sized integer, but the integers you are using are smaller.  Therefore, your math *could* overflow before it gets assigned to a type that would not have overflowed.

Second question:

You don't need a cast that stretches across the screen to fix it.  Just do `s.substr(i, (ssize_t)i + target.length());` or make `i` a larger type to begin with.